# The method to redirect from one page to other on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, mailboxer

In my code, I use something like:

```
<li><%= link_to "Find a meal", {:controller =>'microposts', :action => 'index'} %></li>
```

to redirect to another page.

When I studied the mailbox part, I mentioned the code is:

```
<li><%= link_to "Inbox", mailbox_inbox_path %></li>
```

And this kind of notations appear in other places of this tutorial as well. I thought `mailbox_inbox_path` is a variable already defined somewhere. But I can't find it.

[This is](http://josephndungu.com/tutorials/private-inbox-system-in-rails-with-mailboxer) the tutorial of inbox messaging.

Comment: also check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/routing.html#restful-routing-the-rails-default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mailbox_inbox_path` is not a variable. It's a route helper method generated by Rails based on your routes definition in your `routes.rb` file. Do a:

```
bundle exec rake routes
```

Then, you will be able to see all the available routes for your Rails app and in the leftmost column, you will see the Rails generated helper methods. Just add a `_path` or `_url` to them and you can use them in your views rather than manually specifying `controller` and `action` to `link_to`.

In your particular example from the tutorial, you have the following in the `routes.rb` file:

```
get "mailbox/inbox" => "mailbox#inbox", as: :mailbox_inbox
```

Now, if you do a: `bundle exec rake routes`, you will see this:

```
       Prefix Verb URI Pattern              Controller#Action
mailbox_inbox GET  /mailbox/inbox(.:format) mailbox#inbox
```

So, in the leftmost column you see `mailbox_inbox` which is generated by Rails and you can use this `mailbox_inbox_path` or `mailbox_inbox_url` in your views as they are available as view helper methods.

See [this documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers) and [resources documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Resources/resources) for some more information on this.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works !!!!! Another question: If I add  map.resources :mailbox in my mailbox_controller, it will overwrite something in routes.rb right?

Comment: Also, `map.resources` is an old way (Rails 2) of adding resource routes. see here (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/routing.html#singular-resources). You don't need that for newer version of Rails.

Answer (score 0):

try this command and you will find all such helper methods for mailbox controller

`bundle exec rake routes | grep mailbox`